# GetX replace page (_RouteEntry) from _history. or dispose controller before navigate to the page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

The searchBoxPage is on one screen, the Search result is on SearchResultPage.
Search box page on submit it will route by `Get.toNamed('/search-result?qry=$value');`.

First going to the SearchResult page, SearchResultController onReady is working properly.
Second time when going back searchBoxPage and on submit SearchResultController onReady is NOT working properly.

So I'm looking to dispose SearchResultPage before route to the page.